# If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are ordinals, prove that $\alpha ^ \beta$ is a countable ordinal.

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

In this question I am supposing that both $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are ordinals.

My definition of an ordinal is that: $x$ is an ordinal if $x$ is well-ordered by $\in$ and $x$ is $\in$-transitive.

So far from definitions I have that $\alpha^\beta$ = sup{$\alpha ^ \gamma$ | $\gamma \in \beta$} (where $\in$ = <) and $\beta$ is a limit ordinal.

I also know that since $\omega_1$ is the first uncountable ordinal, then $\alpha$ $\in$ $\omega_1$ is an ordinal. (Not sure if this is correct)

Then I think I just need to prove that $\alpha ^ \beta$ $\in$ $\omega_1$? But I'm not sure how to do that.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Welcome to math.sx! Please show what you have tried so far and where exactly your need help.

Comment: The proof is going to depend on your definition of $\alpha^{\beta}$. Which definition are you working with? The one I've seen is that $\alpha^{\beta}$ is the set of partial functions $\beta \to \alpha$ with finite domain ordered lexicographically, in which case the proof is one of those direct 'do the only thing you can do' proofs.

Comment: I think this is just a case of ordinal exponentiation so I'm not sure

Comment: Your question is *very* unclear. Do you want to prove that the exponent of two countable ordinals is countable? Or that the exponent is an ordinal? The latter is trivial by definition: the supremum of a set of ordinals is an ordinal.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Very sorry, I meant I wanted to prove that the exponent of two countable ordinals is countable.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:**

Prove by induction that the successor of a countable ordinal is countable; conclude that addition of countable ordinals is countable; conclude that a product of countable ordinals is countable; and finally conclude that the exponentiation of two countable ordinals is countable.

The idea behind all of these is the same: countable union of countable sets is countable.

(One can also do that directly, without appealing to the axiom of choice as above, but it does make life simpler.)

Comment: I'm not sure if this is too vague, but if I prove that the countable union of countable sets is countable, then: The successor of a countable ordinal, $x$, written $s(x)$ = $x \cup \{x\}$, is countable because it is a union of two countable sets, $x$ and $\{x\}$. If I claim that since $\alpha + \beta$ = $\alpha$ + 1 + 1... etc, which is the successor of the successor of the successor of... etc ($\alpha$), then this is essentially a successor of countable sets as each successor is countable. Is this correct?

Comment: Recall the definition of $\alpha+\beta$ by induction. It is similar to the one you give for exponentiation.

Comment: $\alpha + \beta$ = sup {$\alpha + \gamma$ | $\gamma \in \beta$ }? for limit ordinal $\beta$

Comment: Yes, that the one.

Comment: Where would this definition fit in to what I (tried) to prove in my first comment?

Comment: That writing $\alpha+1+1+1\ldots$ is not a well-defined expression. And if $A$ is a set of ordinals, then $\sup A=\bigcup A$.

Comment: So $\alpha + \beta$ = sup{$\alpha + \gamma | \gamma \in \beta$} = ⋃ X, for $X$ = the set of ordinals $\alpha + \beta$?

Comment: $\alpha+\beta=\bigcup\{\alpha+\gamma\mid\gamma<\beta\}$.